# Need help with subject verb agreement

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

Need help with *include* vs. *includes*:

> *He's had hits with a massive number of artists that **include** so-and-so, so-and-so, and so-and-so.*

Or should it be *includes*, agreeing with the word "number"?

Comment: ...artists, including ...

Comment: Although you didn't ask this, I'd honestly just reword the sentence.  It's going to be confusing no matter what because the reader is trying to figure out if you're enumerating artists or hits, no matter what form of "include" you use.

Comment: The construction *a number of plural-noun* is itself plural, not singular. Not sure why you would think otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

To specifically answer the question you asked, either works.

> He's had hits with a massive number of artists that include A, B, and C.

In this case, the prepositional object is "artists that include A, B, and C" and the antecedent/referent to "that" is "artists".

> He's had hits with a massive number of artists that includes A, B, and C.

In this case, the prepositional object is limited to "artists" and the antecedent/referent to "that" is "number".

Due to the ambiguous construction, I would go with Edwin's suggestion.

> He's had hits with a massive number of artists, including A, B, and C.